# Convert row value to column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table like below,

```
select * from table1

id  name    Address
1   John    India
1   John    USA
1   John    Spain
2   Tom UK
2   Tom Ecuador
2   Tom Australia
```

I want the output like below,

```
id   name    Address1   Address2    Address3
1    John     India       USA        Spain
2    Tom       UK       Ecuador      Australia
```

Comment: . . I changed the database tag based on the title.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id, name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then address end) as address1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then address end) as address2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then address end) as address3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, name order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ) t
group by id, name;
```